# Cannot login in with Fluent FTP (Error 530 – Not Logged In), but GUI FTP client works

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, dreamhost, fluentftp

This block of code is intended to open a connection between local machine and an FTP server. The server is hosted by [DreamHost](https://dreamhost.com) and I don't know if the issue is in my configuration for the target DreamHost's server. The code throws `WebException`:

> 530 (Not Logged In)

```
// Censored, but all the information given are correct
using (FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient("anaconda.dreamhost.com", "******", "******")) 
{
     ftp.Connect(); // This line
     ..
     ..
}
```

How can I successfully initialize connection to the server?

---

I have also tried login with FileZilla. It seems to be working fine. The log file follows:

> 2021-04-25 18:53:41 2404 1 Status: Connecting to anaconda.dreamhost.com...
> 2021-04-25 18:53:42 2404 1 Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=10
> 2021-04-25 18:53:42 2404 1 Command: open "***********@anaconda.dreamhost.com" 2
> 2021-04-25 18:53:55 2404 1 Status: Using username "********".
> 2021-04-25 18:53:57 2404 1 Command: Pass: ********
> 2021-04-25 18:54:00 2404 1 Status: Connected to anaconda.dreamhost.com
> 2021-04-25 18:54:02 2404 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
> 2021-04-25 18:54:02 2404 1 Command: pwd
> 2021-04-25 18:54:02 2404 1 Response: Current directory is: "/home/*******"
> 2021-04-25 18:54:02 2404 1 Command: ls
> 2021-04-25 18:54:03 2404 1 Status: Listing directory /home/********
> 2021-04-25 18:54:04 2404 1 Status: Directory listing of "/home/******" successful

I am pretty sure that the issue is in my configuration in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using SFTP in FileZilla, not FTP.

So you have to use SFTP library in your code, not FTP library.

See [How to communicate with SFTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1881122/850848).

Comment: Absolutely Working, I Have Changed The Library From FluentFTP To SSH.net And It Works Undoubtedly Fine.